# Can someone help me evaluate this infinite square root expression? I can’t seem to find a way to simplify it.

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

I tried to separate the 5 into 1 + 4 and the 11 into 8 + 3 and so on for the next number. This isn’t like any other problems with nested radicals that i’ve solved. I hope i can learn something from this problem. Please help me! :)
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{19+\sqrt{29+\sqrt{...}}}}}}$$

Side note: 
This is a multiple choice question with the choices are as follow:
A. $\frac{1}{2}$
B. 1
C. 2
D. $\sqrt{3}$
E. $\sqrt{2} - 1$

Comment: I would think it's more useful to note that $$1=1^2+0\\5=2^2+1\\11=3^2+2\\19=4^2+3\\\vdots$$But exactly what to do with that I'm not certain yet.

Comment: @Arthur It can also be looked at as 1, then add 4, then 6, 8, etc.

Comment: @JohnDouma That works too. I was just a bit puzzled about where $8+3$ came from.